# Why is my table creation failing when trying to recreate a deleted DynamoDB table?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table in DynamoDB

Name: TEST

Primary partition key: ID

I have read that the way to empty a DynamoDB table efficiiently is to delete the table and then recreate it.

So, I wrote this:

```
public bool DeleteAllRecords()
{
    DeleteTableRequest deleteTableRequest = new DeleteTableRequest
    {
       TableName = "TEST"
    };

    TableDescription tableDescription = _dynamoDbClient.DeleteTable(deleteTableRequest).TableDescription;

    CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest
    {
        TableName = tableDescription.TableName,
        AttributeDefinitions = tableDescription.AttributeDefinitions,
        KeySchema = tableDescription.KeySchema,
        ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
        {
           ReadCapacityUnits = tableDescription.ProvisionedThroughput.ReadCapacityUnits,
           WriteCapacityUnits = tableDescription.ProvisionedThroughput.WriteCapacityUnits
        }
    };

    CreateTableResponse response = _dynamoDbClient.CreateTable(createTableRequest);

    return true;
}
```

When I run the above I get this Exception.

> 2 validation errors detected: Value null at 'keySchema' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'attributeDefinitions' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

The values of keySchema and attributeDefinitions as returned in tableDescription are empty lists.
If the values were no tin the table to start with, where/how do I get these values; bearing in mind that they may have values at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the async nature of most AWS operations, the following flow would be correct :

- [`DescribeTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) to capture the existing table's details.
- [`DeleteTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html) *(async)*

> After a DeleteTable request, the specified table is in the DELETING state until DynamoDB completes the deletion. If the table is in the ACTIVE state, you can delete it. If a table is in CREATING or UPDATING states, then DynamoDB returns a ResourceInUseException. If the specified table does not exist, DynamoDB returns a ResourceNotFoundException. If table is already in the DELETING state, no error is returned.

- [`DescribeTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) again, until `ResourceNotFoundException`
- [`CreateTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html) *(async)*

> Upon receiving a CreateTable request, DynamoDB immediately returns a response with a TableStatus of CREATING. After the table is created, DynamoDB sets the TableStatus to ACTIVE. You can perform read and write operations only on an ACTIVE table.
>
> [...] You can use the DescribeTable action to check the table status.

- [`DescribeTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) until until `TableStatus === 'ACTIVE'`

*All quotes are from the links contained in this post*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a `DescribeTable` first. That will return the values you are looking for. The response in the `DeleteTable` operation is primarily there to give you the `TableStatus` value.

Keep in mind that a delete operation is not instantaneous, so you'll need to check the status of the table before creating the new table. If the table is still `DELETING` you won't be able to create the new table.

Comment: Shouldn't detection of "still Deleting" or waiting until it "is deleted" be part of the normal locks/transactions covering the Delete Operation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "normal locks/transactions." I only know that a call to `DeleteTable` returns before the table is actually deleted.

Comment: "I only know that a call to DeleteTable returns before the table is actually deleted." Then that is a very unfortunate design decision and a good advice. From Normal DML statements, I kinda expected the previous operation to be properly finished before a new one is attempted. And making sure the old table is at least out of the "Table of Tables" in the Database sounds like something that should be secure.

Comment: DynamoDB is very different from a "normal" database, and most concepts like "table of tables" don't really apply to it. It is "normal" for an asynchronous API call to return before the task is completed.